# Table inside td 100% height not taking the height of outer table

Tags: html, css, html-table

I have table inside table td, I am trying to set inside table td height 100% but it's not working. I am working with bootstrap. Basically I want to cover height of `outer-table td` with `inner-table td`, I have set a border color `red` for `outer-table td` and `black` for `inner-table td`. You can see the `black`  border is not covering the height of `red` border

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<style>
    .outer-table td {
        border: 1px solid red;
    }
    .inner-table td {
        height: 100%;
        border: 1px solid #000;
    }
</style>
<table class="table table-borderless outer-table">
<thead>
<tr>
  <th scope="col">ABC</th>
  <th scope="col">ABCD</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr>
  <td>
    <figure class="figure">
  <img class="figure-img img-fluid rounded" src="data:image/svg+xml;charset=UTF-8,%3Csvg%20width%3D%22400%22%20height%3D%22300%22%20xmlns%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2Fsvg%22%20viewBox%3D%220%200%20400%20300%22%20preserveAspectRatio%3D%22none%22%3E%3Cdefs%3E%3Cstyle%20type%3D%22text%2Fcss%22%3E%23holder_179a5a2c649%20text%20%7B%20fill%3Argba(255%2C255%2C255%2C.75)%3Bfont-weight%3Anormal%3Bfont-family%3AHelvetica%2C%20monospace%3Bfont-size%3A20pt%20%7D%20%3C%2Fstyle%3E%3C%2Fdefs%3E%3Cg%20id%3D%22holder_179a5a2c649%22%3E%3Crect%20width%3D%22400%22%20height%3D%22300%22%20fill%3D%22%23777%22%3E%3C%2Frect%3E%3Cg%3E%3Ctext%20x%3D%22148.84375%22%20y%3D%22158.8828125%22%3E400x300%3C%2Ftext%3E%3C%2Fg%3E%3C%2Fg%3E%3C%2Fsvg%3E" data-holder-rendered="true">
  <figcaption class="figure-caption">A caption for the above image</figcaption>
</figure>
  </td>
  <td>
    <table class="table table-borderless inner-table">
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td class="in">Lorem - Ipsum</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="out">Lorem - Ipsum</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Not sure why you would want to do that, but to get the result you are describing you could try setting the td to `position:absolute`.

Answer (score 0):

What if you just not use table, but divs. You could use flex display to achieve what you want.

See this [example](https://jsfiddle.net/nizamabreu/cfku6rm8/32/)

**HTML**

```
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child1">
    <figure class="figure">
      <div class='title'>ABC</div>
      <img class="figure-img img-fluid rounded" src="data:image/svg+xml;charset=UTF-8,%3Csvg%20width%3D%22400%22%20height%3D%22300%22%20xmlns%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2Fsvg%22%20viewBox%3D%220%200%20400%20300%22%20preserveAspectRatio%3D%22none%22%3E%3Cdefs%3E%3Cstyle%20type%3D%22text%2Fcss%22%3E%23holder_179a5a2c649%20text%20%7B%20fill%3Argba(255%2C255%2C255%2C.75)%3Bfont-weight%3Anormal%3Bfont-family%3AHelvetica%2C%20monospace%3Bfont-size%3A20pt%20%7D%20%3C%2Fstyle%3E%3C%2Fdefs%3E%3Cg%20id%3D%22holder_179a5a2c649%22%3E%3Crect%20width%3D%22400%22%20height%3D%22300%22%20fill%3D%22%23777%22%3E%3C%2Frect%3E%3Cg%3E%3Ctext%20x%3D%22148.84375%22%20y%3D%22158.8828125%22%3E400x300%3C%2Ftext%3E%3C%2Fg%3E%3C%2Fg%3E%3C%2Fsvg%3E" data-holder-rendered="true">
      <figcaption class="figure-caption">A caption for the above image</figcaption>
    </figure>
    
  </div>
  <div class="child2">
    <div class='title'>ABCD</div>
    <div class='quad'>Lorem - Ipsum</div>
    <div class='quad'>Lorem - Ipsum</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.parent { 
  display: flex; 
  border:1px solid red; 
}

.child2 { 
  width: 100%;
  flex: 1; 
  padding: 0px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
 }
 
.quad {
   flex: 1;
   border: solid 1px black;
}
 
.title {
  background-color: #CCC;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`height: 100%` only works as intended if the parent element has a defined height, which is not the case in your example. So you'd have to define a height for the parent `td`. (and avoid paddings and margins for these elements)

Also, you would have to apply `height: 100%` to the `.inner-table`, not to it's cells (which *would*  result in 200% height, if it worked that way...).

Answer (score 0):

### Problems

1. Using Bootstrap sacrifices flexibility. Note that the customized CSS for the red and black borders do not show at all. Bootstrap CSS supersedes the majority of any styles even if said custom styles where positioned last. If you want those borders, you must increase [specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity) by doubling classes (see CSS of demo).
2. Avoid using a ton of extra HTML (especially when using Bootstrap). For every element added you must consider not only the styles Bootstrap imposes but also default styles as well. The OP example has the following vertical margins and padding lengths added:

   | First Column | Second Column |
   | --- | --- |
   | 16px from `<figure>` | 16px from `<table>` |
   |  | 48px from `<td>` |

   These measurements will add on the height of the `<table>` as well as it's contents.

### Solution

Use the attribute [`rowspan`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity) with the value of `'2'` on the first `<td>` to ensure that the cell holding the `<figure>` is will always the height of 2 `<tr>`. Now whatever the height of the `<table>`, the  two columns will always match in height.

1. Remove that inner `<table>`
2. First `<tr>` of `<tbody>` should have 2 `<td>`
3. Add `rowspan='2'` to the first `<td>`
4. Add only one `<td>` to the second `<tr>`

### Demo

```css
.outer-table.outer-table td {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='en'>

<head>
  <meta charset='utf-8'>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <style></style>
</head>

<body>
  <table class="table table-borderless outer-table">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th scope="col">ABC</th>
        <th scope="col">ABCD</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td rowspan='2'>
          <figure class="figure">
            <img class="figure-img img-fluid rounded" src="data:image/svg+xml;charset=UTF-8,%3Csvg%20width%3D%22400%22%20height%3D%22300%22%20xmlns%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2Fsvg%22%20viewBox%3D%220%200%20400%20300%22%20preserveAspectRatio%3D%22none%22%3E%3Cdefs%3E%3Cstyle%20type%3D%22text%2Fcss%22%3E%23holder_179a5a2c649%20text%20%7B%20fill%3Argba(255%2C255%2C255%2C.75)%3Bfont-weight%3Anormal%3Bfont-family%3AHelvetica%2C%20monospace%3Bfont-size%3A20pt%20%7D%20%3C%2Fstyle%3E%3C%2Fdefs%3E%3Cg%20id%3D%22holder_179a5a2c649%22%3E%3Crect%20width%3D%22400%22%20height%3D%22300%22%20fill%3D%22%23777%22%3E%3C%2Frect%3E%3Cg%3E%3Ctext%20x%3D%22148.84375%22%20y%3D%22158.8828125%22%3E400x300%3C%2Ftext%3E%3C%2Fg%3E%3C%2Fg%3E%3C%2Fsvg%3E"
              data-holder-rendered="true">
            <figcaption class="figure-caption">A caption for the above image</figcaption>
          </figure>
        </td>
        <td class="in">Lorem - Ipsum</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="out">Lorem - Ipsum</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>

  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>
```